# Help with voltage labels on flyback converter

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, circuits

I have the following flyback converter circuit made with latex

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 
% Circuit style
\ctikzset{
    resistor = american,
    voltage = american ,
    voltage dir = RP,
    quadpoles/transformer core/inner = 1, %Eliminates the horizontal bars on the transformer
    quadpoles/transformer core/width = 0.6, %Adjusts the width so that the transformers are closer
    diodes/scale = 0.7,
    capacitors/scale = 0.8,
    resistors/scale = 0.8
}
%draw tri and quadpoles
\node[transformer core, anchor = A1, scale = 0.8](transformer) at (2,2){};
\node[circ](c1) at (transformer.inner dot A1){};
\node[circ](c2) at (transformer.inner dot B2){};
\node[npn, anchor = collector, scale = 0.8](npn) at (2,0.25){};

%Primary
\draw (0,0) to [vsource,v=V] ++ (0,2)
 to (0,2) |- (transformer.A1)
 (transformer.A2) -- (npn.collector)
 (npn.emitter) -| (0,0);
 
%Secondary
 \draw (transformer.B1) to[Do] ++ (2,0) coordinate(A)
 (A) to[C] (A |- transformer.B2)
 (transformer.B2) to[short,i = $i_s$] (A |- transformer.B2);
 
 \draw (A) ++(1,0) coordinate(B)
 (A)--(B)
 (B) to [R,v=U] (B|- transformer.B2)
 (B|- transformer.B2) -- (A |- transformer.B2);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Flyback converter]

Now. I need to be able to draw some voltage labels. In particular I need the voltage in the primary and secondary transformer windings and between collector emmiter and base emmiter of the transistor. Since nodes do not allow for the current labels I tried to use the \draw [open]

I simply added at the end of the tikzpicture the following lines

```
\draw (transformer.A1) to [open, v = $v_p$ , f = $i_p$] (transformer.A2);
\draw (transformer.B1) to [open, v = $v_s$] (transformer.B2);
\draw (npn.collector) to [open, v = $v_Q$] (npn.emitter);
\draw (npn.base) to [open, v = $v_{be}$] (npn.emitter);
```

[image: Flyback converter with labels]

As you can see the labels overlap with the components, which is not very good for legibility

I have more or less managed to solve the issue with the following modifications to the code that draws the labels

```
\draw ([xshift = -20]transformer.A1) to [open, v = $v_p$ , f = $i_p$] ([xshift = -20]transformer.A2);
\draw ([xshift = 10]transformer.B1) to [open, v = $v_s$] ([xshift = 10]transformer.B2);
\draw ([xshift = 10]npn.collector) to [open, v = $v_Q$] ([xshift = 10]npn.emitter);
\draw ([xshift = -5,yshift = -5]npn.base) to [open, v = $v_{be}$] (npn.emitter);
```

[image: Flyback convertet with better placed labels]

**My question:**

As you can see this fixes the issue rather nicely. However, I was wondering if there would be a better way to do this.

Feel free to also point out any other mistakes/issues with the whole circuit. I am very new to this package and I am just learning

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution proposed by the OP is correct; I propose an alternative one here. The voltage on `open` is normally thought to label a centered voltage, but you can use the `legacy` option to `open voltage position` to have it behave like you seem to desire. You can define a style to simplify the positioning. Notice that the `voltage shift` amount is a bit of trial and miss, that part of the code is really rarely used, and I will look into it; it seems to be jerky outside the `-1,1` range.

Moreover, it seems that you like the `raised` option for voltages more than the `american` one, so let's use them consistently across the diagram. For the same consistency, style options are better suited to the preamble of the document.

The current is better added to `short` element or to path element in general, it's better semantically clear where it is...

In general, I find the drawing too tight for the quantity of information you want to add, so I have given it a  bit of spacing --- although I'd probably prefer it even more spacey.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
% Circuit style
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{
    resistor = american,
    voltage = raised ,
    voltage dir = RP,
    quadpoles/transformer core/inner = 1, %Eliminates the horizontal bars on the transformer
    quadpoles/transformer core/width = 0.6, %Adjusts the width so that the transformers are closer
    diodes/scale = 0.7,
    capacitors/scale = 0.8,
    resistors/scale = 0.8
}

%% shifted open voltage 
\tikzset{open shifted/.style={
    open ,open voltage position=legacy, voltage shift=-0.9}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
%draw tri and quadpoles
\node[transformer core, anchor = A1, scale = 0.8](transformer) at (2,2){};
\node[circ](c1) at (transformer.inner dot A1){};
\node[circ](c2) at (transformer.inner dot B2){};
\node[npn, anchor = collector, scale = 0.8](npn) at (2,0){};

%Primary
\draw (0,0) to [vsource,v=V] ++(0,2)
 to [short, f=$i_p$] (transformer.A1) % current here
 (transformer.A2) -- (npn.collector)
 (npn.emitter) --++(0,-0.5) -| (0,0);

%Secondary
 \draw (transformer.B1) to[Do] ++ (2,0) coordinate(A)
 (A) to[C] (A |- transformer.B2)
 (transformer.B2) to[short,i = $i_s$] (A |- transformer.B2);

 \draw (A) ++(1,0) coordinate(B)
 (A)--(B)
 (B) to [R,v^=U] (B|- transformer.B2)
 (B|- transformer.B2) -- (A |- transformer.B2);

\draw (npn.C) to[open shifted, v^=$v_Q$](npn.E);
\draw (npn.B) to[open shifted, v=$v_{be}$, voltage shift=-1](npn.E);
\draw (transformer.A1) to[open shifted, v=$v_p$](transformer.A2);
\draw (transformer.B1) to[open shifted, v^=$v_s$](transformer.B2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]